Does ConnectorX have support for Azure managed identities?
At the moment using ConnectorX and Polars to extract data from SQL Server into a Polars DataFrame. I want to remove the SQL credentials and update to using a managed identity. Do ConnectorX and Polars have support for Azure managed identities?
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import polars as pl
from timeit import default_timer as timer

load_dotenv()


def extract_from_db():
    env_upper = os.environ["envUpp"]
    env_lower = env_upper.lower()
    username = os.environ["UID"]
    password = os.environ["PWD"]
    host = f"my_host"
    port = "1433"
    db = f"nyd_db"
    view = "my.view"
    conn = f"mssql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}?encrypt=true"
    datetime_limit = str(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=365))[:-3]
    query = f"SELECT * from {view} WHERE RecordTime > '{datetime_limit}'"

    print(query)
    start = timer()
    data = pl.read_sql(query, conn)
    end = timer()
    print("time taken to load data into df=", timedelta(seconds=end - start))
    num_of_rows = data.shape[0]
    num_of_cols = data.shape[1]
    print(f"number of columns in df: {num_of_cols}")
    print(f"number of rows in df: {num_of_rows}")
    return data`


I might be wrong, but before you switch to a Managed Identity, wouldn't fixing the injection issue be a better use of your time?

@Thom A that's an easy fix just trying to get managed identity working then can implement way to fix injection
